# Vba requery parameter syntax

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to set the parameter for a requery command, but I can´t find the correct syntax.

```
tbTreinamentosConc.Requery Profissional = prof
```

tbTreinamentosConc refers to table Trn_Done, which has the column Profissional, among the others and prof is the parameter I want to be used when searching in the table Trn_Done, in the field Profissional.

What is the correct way to get it working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing a `.Requery` method that takes an argument. What sort of object is `tbTreinamentosConc`?

Comment: I think you will need to provide more information

Answer (score 0):

A requery will simply update the information in a given object, you can't pass arguments to it. You can however write an SQL statement to query for something specific...

> > Dim strSQL As String
> >
> > strSQL = "SELECT  *  " & _ 
> >                           "FROM  tbTreinamentosConc  " 
> >                      "WHERE Profissional ='" & txtInput &  ";"
> >
> > DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

txtInput will be a text box on your field that you can enter the 'prof' parameter into; This should work.